# asmx WebService insisting on methods it calls in other classes having nullable parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I was trying to simplify some code in a library shared between a winform and a webapp (written by someone else) by taking several methods/properties that were nullable, but for which nullable values were never passed in/nulls were never consumed into non-nullable ones.

This worked fine in the winform app, and the webapp doesn't have any compile time problems but when I first ran it, it failed reporting an error that it couldn't find the old version of the method that took `DateTime?` parameters, despite the fact that the values being passed were non-nullable `DateTime`s.  When I added back an overload with `DateTime?` parameters it worked only to generate an error elsewhere in the code due to a property that had been changed from `int?` to `int`.

After confirming that an overload with `DateTime?` parameters would work as a fix, I commented the overload back out to try and figure out why it was insisting on calling that version.  At some point while I was fiddling with it (doing forced rebuilds, etc), it suddenly stopped generating the errors even though I'd reverted the two .cs files to the version where they were initially failing.  At this point it's working, but I have no idea what went wrong initially or how it was fixed, and I'm very leery of continuing on until I know what happened.

Approximate error message (from memory):
`Method not found: 'null
 NameSpace.StaticClass.StaticMethod( IFoo foo, IBar[] bar, DateTime? padStart, DateTime? padEnd )'.`

Actual error message:
`Method not found: 'System.Nullable`1 NameSpace.OtherClass.get_Number()'.`

Method in MyWebService.asmx:

```
   [WebMethod( EnableSession = true )]
    public string DoStuff( string jsonFoo, string startDate, string endDate )
    {
        try
        {
            IFoo foo = Deserialize<IFoo>( jsonFoo );

                IBar[] bar = null;

                DateTime padStart = DateTime.Parse(startDate);
                DateTime padEnd = DateTime.Parse(endDate);


                StaticClass.StaticMethod( foo, bar, padStart, padEnd );
        }
    }
```

Method in StaticClass:

```
    public static void StaticMethod( IFoo foo, IBar[] bar, DateTime padStart, DateTime padEnd )
    {
    }
```

Comment: Is the .asmx webservice you mentioned the webapp that you're working in, or your webapp references a webservice where the changes were made?

Comment: It's part of the solution being built and run in visial studio.

Comment: This could be something fairly obvious I suppose, my experience in .net has been desktop apps almost exclusively.

Comment: If your website has a web reference to the asmx service, and the asmx service is what changed, then the web reference would have to be updated. It's been a while since I've worked with web projects, so I don't remember the specifics, but it may happen when you do a Rebuild vs. a Build. You can also right-click the web reference and select the "Update Web Reference" option (or whatever exactly it's called).

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of clearing out the obvious problems first - did you rebuild any client side proxies/stubs that were built against the service?  The client code could still have been generating service requests to the v1 service definition rather than the shiny new v2 one.  Just a thought?

Comment: Initially I just clicked the run button in visual studio.  AFAIK everything needed by the site is included in the solution.

Comment: It's perfectly possible this isn't the problem at all but just to eliminate it, I would do as Joel C suggests in the OP comments and do an update of the web references on the client project within the solution.

Comment: Unless newer versions of visual studio let webreferences live outside the webreference folder there aren't any.  All the web parts (server and clientside) are in a single project.  The business logic and data layers are separated out; but that's as far as the prior devs separated anything.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's just an issue with how the .NET runtime handles dynamic compilation in a Website project. In a Web Application you have to rebuild it anytime you make changes, and the whole app gets compiled into a .dll like other projects. In a Website with dynamic compilation, the runtime basically determines how your pages get separated into .dll's and when they need to be rebuilt. Since your situation involved static methods in what sounds like is a separate project/.dll, but the page in your site never changed, the runtime probably just never re-linked against the updated .dll. Then if at some point you made a change to the page that would have caused it to be recompiled, it would suddenly recognize the new methods in your static class. Of course at this point, it's just guessing ;)

If you have a problem like this again, though, I'd recommend right-clicking the Website in Solution Explorer and doing a "Rebuild"

Comment: I just tried testing this via regression (switching static class to take DateTime?'s and asmx to pass DateTime?'s).  Despite a rebuild, and then a clean followed by a rebuild; it's still failing because it's looking for a version of the method that takes DateTime's.  I finally tried changing the default port and restarting visual studio itself, still didn't work.